# nav drawer disappears when viewer breakpoint is below md

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a dashboard that needs to be shown if the viewer size sm and above but hidden if is xs.

The original template i had is below.  The problem is that below md the navigation drawer would be hidden.

```
<div id="app">
    <template>
        <v-app id="inspire">
            <v-navigation-drawer
                v-model="drawer"
                expand-on-hover
                app                    
                clipped
                class="d-none d-sm-inline"
            >
                <v-list >
                <v-list-item
                >
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>
                            assignment
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                            assignment
                        </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer>
        </v-app>
    </template>
</div>
```

EDIT:
This is a full example.  Below 1264px width the drawer will disappear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->         
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.0.96/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="app">
    <template>
        <v-app id="inspire">
            <v-navigation-drawer
                v-model="drawer"
                expand-on-hover
                app                    
                clipped
                class="d-none d-sm-inline"
            >
                <v-list >
                <v-list-item
                >
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>
                            assignment
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                            assignment
                        </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer>
        </v-app>
    </template>
</div>
        <script  type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015">
            new Vue
                 (
                    { 
                       el: "#app", 
                       vuetify: new Vuetify(), 
                       data:  
                       { 
                           drawer: null, 
                       },  
                    }
                 );     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: The suggested solution by Mr Rossi also doesnt work and has the same behaviour

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->         
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.0.96/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="app">
    <template>
        <v-app id="inspire">
            <v-navigation-drawer
                v-model="drawer"
                expand-on-hover
                app                    
                clipped
                :class="{'display': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp ? 'none' : 'inline'}"
            >
                <v-list >
                <v-list-item
                >
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>
                            assignment
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                            assignment
                        </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer>
        </v-app>
    </template>
</div>
        <script  type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015">
            new Vue
                 (
                    { 
                       el: "#app", 
                       vuetify: new Vuetify(), 
                       data:  
                       { 
                           drawer: null, 
                       },  
                    }
                 );     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not think its problem with vuetify, can you upload a work example that everyone can see?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that for some reason vuetify was moving the navigation drawer 100% to the left and so hiding it. My solution is to override that move by adding the style 'style="transform: translateX(0%);top:48px;"' as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->         
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.0.96/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="app">
    <template>
        <v-app id="inspire">
            <v-navigation-drawer
                v-model="drawer"
                expand-on-hover
                app                    
                clipped
style="transform: translateX(0%);top:48px;"
                class="d-none d-sm-inline"
            >
                <v-list >
                <v-list-item
                >
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>
                            assignment
                        </v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>
                            assignment
                        </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-navigation-drawer>
        </v-app>
    </template>
</div>
        <script  type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015">
            new Vue
                 (
                    { 
                       el: "#app", 
                       vuetify: new Vuetify(), 
                       data:  
                       { 
                           drawer: null, 
                       },  
                    }
                 );     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The translateX overrides the move to the left and top:48px sets the nav drawer to be below an app bar i had in the original, if you dont have an app bar then you wont need it.

I am not sure if this is a bug in vuetify v2.0.11 but it works with that fix. Hope this is helpful to someone, it took me an hour or so to find and fix

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is about breakpoints.
You can use Vuetify breakpoints to show or hide some elements.
For example if you want to display it for sm and above you can use this:

```
:class="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp ? "d-inline" : "d-block"
```

or simply hide it if is xs:

```
:class="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly ? "d-inline" : "d-block"
```

This is the docs page on how to use breakpoints: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints#breakpoints

Comment: This doesnt work, it behaves the same way as before.  I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

For vuetify v3, you should set the `mobile-breakpoint` property to a lower breakpoint if you don't want the drawer to hide on lower resolutions.

You can find it in the vuetify [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props-mobile-breakpoint).

Example:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    expand-on-hover
    rail
    mobile-breakpoint="xs"
>
```